# assigning user defined name to array element in reservation system

Tags: c#

I need help on my console based aeroplane seat reservation code (written in c#).

Trying to implement:

- Search seating by passenger name/seat number

Below is code from the airplane class which i thought was relevant for the question i'm asking, i can provide more if necessary (the seating method has been simplified since it was quite big), thank you:

```
public static void seating()
    {
        Console.Write("Key: " + "* - Available " + " X - Occupied" + "\n" + "\n");
        //FC

        Console.Write("     \tA\tB\tC\tD\tE\tF");
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.Write("Row 1\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[0, 0]);
        Console.Write("\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[0, 1]);
        Console.Write("\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[0, 2]);
        Console.Write("\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[0, 3]);
        Console.Write("\n");

        Console.Write("Row 2\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[1, 0]);
        Console.Write("\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[1, 1]);
        Console.Write("\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[1, 2]);
        Console.Write("\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[1, 3]);
        Console.Write("\n");


        //EC

        Console.Write("Row 3\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[2, 0]);
        Console.Write("\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[2, 1]);
        Console.Write("\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[2, 2]);
        Console.Write("\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[2, 3]);
        Console.Write("\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[2, 4]);
        Console.Write("\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[2, 5]);
        Console.Write("\n");

        Console.Write("Row 4\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[3, 0]);
        Console.Write("\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[3, 1]);
        Console.Write("\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[3, 2]);
        Console.Write("\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[3, 3]);
        Console.Write("\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[3, 4]);
        Console.Write("\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[3, 5]);
        Console.Write("\n");

        Console.Write("Row 5\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[4, 0]);
        Console.Write("\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[4, 1]);
        Console.Write("\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[4, 2]);
        Console.Write("\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[4, 3]);
        Console.Write("\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[4, 4]);
        Console.Write("\t");
        Console.Write(airchar[4, 5]);
        Console.Write("\n");

        public static void passengers()
    {
        if (ticket == "FC")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number of passengers traveling together (1 or 2 for First Class): ");
            numPassenger = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (numPassenger == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Passenger 1 Full Name (BLOCK CAPITAL): ");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if (numPassenger == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Passenger 1 Full Name (BLOCK CAPITAL): ");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Passenger 2 Full Name (BLOCK CAPITAL): ");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        else if (ticket == "EC")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number of passengers traveling together (1 to 3 for Economy): ");
            numPassenger = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (numPassenger == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Passenger 1 Full Name (BLOCK CAPITAL): ");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if (numPassenger == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Passenger 1 Full Name (BLOCK CAPITAL): ");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Passenger 2 Full Name (BLOCK CAPITAL): ");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if (numPassenger == 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Passenger 1 Full Name (BLOCK CAPITAL): ");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Passenger 2 Full Name (BLOCK CAPITAL): ");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Passenger 3 Full Name (BLOCK CAPITAL): ");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                return; 
            }
        }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Just a question before an answer... Is this an academic solution? Because I am wondering, since you are planning on store everything in memory, seems to be. So I can answer something apppropriated to your current architecture.

Answer (score 1):

I thought quickly on a form to improve your solution modeling. I believe it can be done in better ways, but this can be a good start.

Seems like you need to not only store seat information, but to quickly find it at will. So I made a serie of objects to Help storing, changing and finding seats by position or passenger names. Hope it helps.

Helper Classes code:

```
public class AirplaneSeating
{
    private List<Seat> seats;

    public AirplaneSeating()
    {
        seats = new List<Seat>();

        // Filling FC Rows
        for (byte row = 1; row <= 5; row++)
            for (byte column = 1; column <= 4; column++)
                seats.Add(new Seat(row, column));

        // Filling EC Rows
        for (byte row = 6; row <= 35; row++)
            for (byte column = 1; column <= 6; column++)
                seats.Add(new Seat(row, column));
    }

    // You can use this indexed property to search for a seat by it's address
    public Seat this[string address]
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                var start = 0;
                var end = address.Length - 1;
                var row = byte.Parse(address.Substring(start, end));
                var col = address[end];

                return seats.First(
                    s => s.Position.Row == row && s.Position.Column.Name == col);
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    // You can use this indexed property if you need to loop through seats
    public Seat this[byte row, byte column]
    {
        get
        {
            return seats.FirstOrDefault(
                s => s.Position.Row == row && s.Position.Column.Number == column);
        }
    }

    // This method can be used to find a seat occupied by a passenger
    public Seat FindSeatOccupiedBy(string passengerName)
    {
        return seats.FirstOrDefault(
            s => s.Passenger.ToUpper().Contains(passengerName.ToUpper()));
    }

    public void ReserveSeat()
    {
        char ticketType = char.MinValue;
        byte passengersTogether = 0;
        int maxPassengersTogether;
        bool inputOk = false;

        while (ticketType != 'F' && ticketType != 'S')
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the ticket type (F = First Class, S = Second Class): ");
            ticketType = char.ToUpper(Console.ReadLine()[0]);
        }

        if (ticketType == 'F')
            maxPassengersTogether = 2;
        else
            maxPassengersTogether = 3;

        while (!inputOk && (passengersTogether < 1 || 
            passengersTogether > maxPassengersTogether))
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the number of passengers traveling together (1 or {0}): ",
                maxPassengersTogether);

            inputOk = byte.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out passengersTogether);
        }

        for (byte passengerNumber = 1; 
            passengerNumber <= passengersTogether; 
            passengerNumber++)
        {
            Console.Write("Passenger {0} full name (BLOCK CAPITAL): ", passengerNumber);
            string passengerName = Console.ReadLine();

            Seat seat = null;
            string lastSeatAddress = null;

            // Choosen seat address must be valid (or else it will return null)
            // Choosen seat must match ticket type
            // Choosen seat must not be occupied
            while (seat == null || 
                seat.Class != (ClassType)ticketType || 
                seat.Status == SeatStatus.Occupied)
            {
                if (seat != null)
                {
                    if (seat.Class != (ClassType)ticketType)
                        Console.WriteLine("Seat does not match ticket type.");

                    if (seat.Status == SeatStatus.Occupied)
                        Console.WriteLine("This seat is occupied by {0}.",
                            seat.Passenger);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (lastSeatAddress != null)
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid seat address.");
                }

                Console.Write("Enter passenger seat (example: 1A): ");
                lastSeatAddress = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
                seat = this[lastSeatAddress];
            }

            seat.Passenger = passengerName;

            Console.WriteLine("Seat {0} reserved for passenger {1}.",
                seat.Position, seat.Passenger);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Reservation complete.");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public void PrintPassengersToConsole()
    {
        var occupiedSeats = seats.Where(s => s.Status == SeatStatus.Occupied);

        if (occupiedSeats.Any())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Seating\tPassenger Name");

            foreach (var seat in occupiedSeats
                    .OrderBy(s => s.Position.Row)
                    .ThenBy(s => s.Position.Column.Number))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}     \t{1}",
                    seat.Position,
                    seat.Passenger);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The airplane does not have any reservation.");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    // This method can be called to print the seating to console, like you needed
    public void PrintToConsole()
    {
        Console.Write("Key: " + "* - Available " + " X - Occupied" + "\n" + "\n");
        Console.Write("     \tA\tB\tC\tD\tE\tF");
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (var row in seats.GroupBy(s => s.Position.Row)
            .OrderBy(r => r.Key))
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("Row {0}\t", row.Key));

            foreach (var column in row.GroupBy(s => s.Position.Column.Number)
                .OrderBy(c => c.Key))
            {
                foreach (var seat in column)
                {
                    Console.Write((char)seat.Status);
                    Console.Write("\t");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

// This class represents your Seat
public class Seat
{
    public Seat(byte row, char column)
    {
        Position = new SeatPosition(row, column);
    }

    public Seat(byte row, byte column)
    {
        Position = new SeatPosition(row, column);
    }

    // Set Passenger to null to make the seat available.
    public string Passenger { get; set; }

    public SeatPosition Position { get; private set; }

    public SeatStatus Status
    {
        get
        {
            // When you assign a passenger to a seat, status will change
            if (Passenger == null)
                return SeatStatus.Available;
            else
                return SeatStatus.Occupied;
        }
    }

    public ClassType Class
    {
        get
        {
            // Remember to change this if you want more rows of FC
            if (Position.Row <= 5)
                return ClassType.FirstClass;
            else
                return ClassType.SecondClass;
        }
    }
}

// This enum represents the status of the Seat
public enum SeatStatus
{
    Available = '*',
    Occupied = 'X'
}

// This enum represents the class type of the Seat
public enum ClassType
{
    FirstClass = 'F',
    SecondClass = 'S'
}

// This class represents a seat position
public class SeatPosition
{
    public SeatPosition(byte row, char column)
    {
        Row = row;
        Column = new SeatColumn(column);
    }

    public SeatPosition(byte row, byte column)
    {
        Row = row;
        Column = new SeatColumn(column);
    }

    public byte Row { get; private set; }

    public SeatColumn Column { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}{1}", Row, Column.Name);
    }
}

// This class is to help defining and printing seat columns
public class SeatColumn
{
    public SeatColumn(byte number)
    {
        Number = number;
    }

    public SeatColumn(char name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public byte Number { get; set; }

    public char Name
    {
        get { return NumberToName(Number); }
        set { Number = NameToNumber(value); }
    }

    private static char NumberToName(byte number)
    {
        switch (number)
        {
            case 1:
                return 'A';
            case 2:
                return 'B';
            case 3:
                return 'C';
            case 4:
                return 'D';
            case 5:
                return 'E';
            case 6:
                return 'F';
        }

        throw new Exception("Invalid column number.");
    }

    private static byte NameToNumber(char name)
    {
        switch (name)
        {
            case 'A':
                return 1;
            case 'B':
                return 2;
            case 'C':
                return 3;
            case 'D':
                return 4;
            case 'E':
                return 5;
            case 'F':
                return 6;
        }

        throw new Exception("Invalid column name.");
    }
}
```

Below I made a quick demonstration code on how to use those classes. I guess this will make your life much easier when implementing your application. You just need to take data from the input, like you were doing.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var seating = new AirplaneSeating();

    // Use PrintToConsole to print seating to screen.
    seating.PrintToConsole();

    // You can find a specific seat by its position.
    var seat1 = seating["1A"]; // Gives me seat 1A
    var seat2 = seating[1, 1]; // Also gives me seat 1A

    // Then you can put a passenger on this seat if you want.
    seat2.Passenger = "Jhon";

    // When you set a passenger name to the seat, its status will change.
    Console.WriteLine("Seat 1A status is {0}.", seat1.Status); // Occupied

    // You can find a specific seat by passenger name.
    // This line of code gives me seat 1A, wich is now Jhon's seat.
    var occupiedSeat1 = seating.FindSeatOccupiedBy("Jhon");

    // You can find by typing a part of the passenger name, 
    // and you don't need to worry about capitalization
    var occupiedSeat2 = seating.FindSeatOccupiedBy("JHO");

    // You can print seat information on console.
    Console.WriteLine("Seat {0} is occupied by {1}.", 
        occupiedSeat2.Position, occupiedSeat2.Passenger);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This is a practical example to your application. Put this code into your Program class (the one with Main method).

```
static AirplaneSeating seating;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    seating = new AirplaneSeating();
    Options();
}

static void Options()
{
    bool optionOk = false;
    byte option = 0;

    while (!optionOk)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Select from the following menu:");
        Console.WriteLine("1. To Add Passenger");
        Console.WriteLine("2. To View Seating");
        Console.WriteLine("3. To View Passenger List");
        Console.WriteLine("4. Quit Application" + "\n");

        byte.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out option);

        if (option >= 1 && option <= 4)
        {
            optionOk = true;
        }
    }

    switch (option)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.Clear();
            seating.ReserveSeat();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Please press enter to return to main menu.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            Options();
            break;

        case 2:
            Console.Clear();
            seating.PrintToConsole();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Please press enter to return to main menu.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            Options();
            break;

        case 3:
            Console.Clear();
            seating.PrintPassengersToConsole();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Please press enter to return to main menu.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            Options();
            break;

        case 4:
            Environment.Exit(0);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you just need to change the two for loops. The initial value is the first row/col, and the final value is the final row/col. I made it look like your example (first class rows 1 to 2, and second class rows 3 to 5). Same principle applies to columns.

Comment: Put the row of first class 1 to 5, and the second class, 6 to 35.

Comment: Wich kind of update are you trying to do? I guessed you only needed to fill passangers, after fill all seats in the class initialization.

Comment: Alright, I will adjust your Main class laters. I'm quite busy at the moment.

Comment: Added a practical example of a working application. Try it.

Comment: For my practical example to work, you need to implement my first code, the one with the classes. I updated it  since my last contact, be sure to update it in your code, too.

Comment: Sorry, I made a bug there on the indexer property (public Seat this[string address]). I've corrected it, just copy from the classes.

Comment: @Delford - we say thank you for answers not with comments and certainly not by deleting the question, but by up votes and accepting answer